# Having trouble getting text to animate left with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I am working on getting some text to drop and then create a cloud of dust then I want it to shift to the left. I have got it to drop on the page creating the dust but it just stops after that. I cant get it to move to the left at all. Any suggestions? Thanks ahead of time.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('p.textDrop').css({
    transform: 'scale(10)', 
    opacity: 0.2,
    position: 'relative'

}).animate({
    transform: 'scale(1)', 
    opacity: 0.8

}, 2000, 'easeOutQuart' );

$('#dustPuffs').delay(1000).show(600).css({
    opacity: 0.2,
    transform: scale(.75),   
}
).animate({
    transform: 'scale(300,200)', 
    opacity: 1,
    left: "300"
}, 6000, function () {


});

});
```

Comment: In order for left to work the parent must also be displayed relatively or absolutely. Also make sure you add all the vendor prefix styles for transform as well. And left should be 300px not just 300.

Comment: have you checked the console for errors? there are a few things in there that look like they will throw an error.

Comment: Actually it is error free. Just sort of stops after the text drops on the page.

Comment: It's possible you're using some plugin to jquery I don't have, but that code throws an error on the ease out as well as on the 3rd scale not in quotes for me. ( I think you might also want +=300 as your left value).

Answer (score 0):

To follow up from comments, I would make sure you're using chrome's dev console to watch for errors as the code you have there will throw an error. Here's the code with the two errors fixed/removed, and it runs correctly for me. Obviously on two generic elements, as I don't know what your actual elements are.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.textDrop').css({
        transform: 'scale(5)', 
        opacity: 0.2,
        position: 'relative'

    }).animate({
        transform: 'scale(1)', 
        opacity: 0.8

    }, 5000);

    $('#dustPuffs').delay(1000).show(600).css({
        opacity: 0.2,
        transform: "scale(.75)",   
    }
    ).animate({
        transform: 'scale(300,200)', 
        opacity: 1,
        left: "+=300"
    }, 10000, function () {


    });

});
```